# How to use np.arange to get set of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How to get values in range of `10**-4 to 10**4`  `(ie., 10**-4,10**-3,10**-2.... etc)`.

I need values such as 10**-4 then  10**-3 then 10**-2 and so on until 10**4

I tried something like `np.arange(10**-4, 10**-3)` but this is giving me a lot of numbers.

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: `x=np.arange(-4,4);  x=10**x`.  Generate the powers, and then use the array to calculate a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an in-built NumPy function for that called [`logspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html)

```
values = np.logspace(-4, 4, 9)
#array([1.e-04, 1.e-03, 1.e-02, 1.e-01, 1.e+00, 1.e+01, 1.e+02, 1.e+03, 1.e+04])
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you use this:

```
[10**i for i in range(-4,5) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.arange` gives evenly spaced numbers. In your case difference between consecutive numbers changes at each step.

You can do something like:

```
a = [10**i for i in range(-4, 5)]
>>> [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
```

And convert to numpy array if you want

```
np.array(a)
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you :) Is it possible to get it using `np.arange`?